# Go websocket test acting strange

Tags: go, testing, websocket

So basically I'm writing a go test for my chat application and for some reason the if I write Test_saveMessage function in the top of this file my tests go through and they work fine, however if I write the Test_InitRouter in the top of this file - my server opens and the test doesn't finish. As if it would be listening for more requests. Does anyone know the reason of why this could be happening? Here is the that does not work code:

```
package messenger

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)
var testMessage = Message{
    Username: "Name",
    Message:  "Test message"}


//Tests InitRouter both sending and receiving messages
func Test_InitRouter(t *testing.T) {
    var receivedMessage Message

    //Create test server with the InitRouter handler
    s := httptest.NewServer(InitRouter())
    defer s.Close()

    // Convert URL from http to ws
    u := "ws" + strings.TrimPrefix(s.URL, "http")
    fmt.Println(u)

    // Connect to the test server
    ws, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u, nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    defer ws.Close()

    //Send message to the server read received message and see if it's the same
    if err != ws.WriteJSON(testMessage) {
        t.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    err = ws.ReadJSON(&receivedMessage)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    if receivedMessage != testMessage {
        t.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
}

//Test for the saveMessage function
func Test_saveMessage(t *testing.T) {
    saveMessage(testMessage)
    assert.Equal(t, 1, len(messages), "Expected to have 1 message")
}
```

As soon as I move the Test_saveMessage function to the top it starts working properly.

Here is the code for the handler:

```
package messenger

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net/http"
)

func InitRouter() http.Handler {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Get("/", GetWebsocket)
    return r
}

var clients = make(map[*websocket.Conn]bool) // connected clients
var broadcast = make(chan Message)           // broadcast channel

var messages = []Message{}

func GetWebsocket(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Upgrade initial GET request to a websocket
    upgrader := websocket.Upgrader{}
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    // Close the connection when the function returns
    defer ws.Close()

    // Register our new client and send him the chat history
    clients[ws] = true
    serveInitialMessages(ws)
    //initialize message sending logic
    sendMessages(ws)
}

// Sends messages from a particular websocket to the channel
func sendMessages(ws *websocket.Conn){
    for {
        var msg Message
        // Read in a new message as JSON and map it to a Message object
        err := ws.ReadJSON(&msg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Info(err)
            delete(clients, ws)
            break
        }
        // Send the newly received message to the broadcast channel
        broadcast <- msg
        saveMessage(msg)
    }
}

func HandleMessages() {
    for {
        // Grab the next message from the broadcast channel
        msg := <-broadcast
        fmt.Println(msg)
        // Send it out to every client that is currently connected
        for client := range clients {
            err := client.WriteJSON(msg)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("error: %v", err)
                client.Close()
                delete(clients, client)
            }
        }
    }
}

func saveMessage(m Message) {
    if len(messages) >= 50 {
        messages = messages[1:]
    }
    messages = append(messages, m)
}

func serveInitialMessages(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    for _, m := range messages {
        err := ws.WriteJSON(m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code that sets `messages`.

Comment: Added the code to the post.

Comment: The tests are order dependent because of the shared state in the package-level variable `messages`.  Reset that variable in each test.  Because the server does not immediately echo a client's message back to client, `Test_InitRouter` blocks forever waiting for a message when there are no saved messages.  The application and test have several data races.

Comment: Well i tried adding a line `messages = []Message{}` in both tests, but that did not do the trick. Is it possible, that the `messages` variable is't the problem?

Comment: Clearing the messages fixes the dependence on test order.  Now you need to fix the stuck test and data races.